# dbx variables not working

Tags: dbx

I am debugging a piece of code which has complex data structures in it. I want to use dbx variables to hold the values of these structures to avoid pointer indirection every time to see the contents.
When I do, something like `set $myTemp=*ptr->curValue`, it does not give any error, but issuing a display command does not show up myTemp. Also when I execute `print $myTemp`, I get no output and no error either. Doing `print myTemp`(without dollar sign) gives error which goes like "myTemp not defined in local scope ..". Any ideas what could be wrong here.
I am using solaris 10 here.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to use `set` in dbx.  You can just specify the `variablename=thevalue`, also no spaces. Otherwise it gets all honked up.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a syntax error.  Dbx uses the ksh shell syntax and you are using a dollar sign prefix on the name of the variable (according to your description).

Instead of saying:

```
set $foo=bar
```

say this:

```
set foo=bar
```